# What is the genealogy of all the 'Bob' clones

Tags: bobiverse

With the new release of *[For We Are Many](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33395557-for-we-are-many)* I realize that it have lost track of which Bobs were created when on the first book.

Is there a 'family tree' chart of all the Bobs?  My searches on the Internet hasn't revealed anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly a family tree, but a timeline with all the Bob clones and important events:
http://dennisetaylor.org/2017/03/04/timeline-of-we-are-legion/

Edit: The author has created a family tree:
http://dennisetaylor.org/2017/04/07/genealogy-of-the-bobs/

Answer (score 3):

First, *I loved that book*.

Second, I don't think there are any **complete** family trees, but here are two good places to bookmark and keep track of:

http://wearebob.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Characters

http://www.bobiverse.net/category/characters/